# MongoDB C# Query for 'Like' on string

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

i am using official mongodb c# driver. 
i want to query mongodb simliar to SQL Like 
something like `db.users.find({name:/Joe/}` in c# driver

Comment: Apparently there is a class called `MongoRegex` for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527443/how-to-use-mongoregex-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Comment: not able to use it for this case properly

Answer (score 47, accepted):

c# query will looks like:

```
Query.Matches("name", BsonRegularExpression.Create(new Regex("Joe")));
```

### Update:

As per @RoberStam suggestion, there is more simple way to do this:

```
Query.Matches("name", "Joe")
```

Comment: You could just write: Query.Matches("name", "Joe")

Comment: How would you do it with the new 2.0 driver ?

Answer (score 36):

For the c# driver  2.1 (MongoDB 3.0)

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("<<name of the collection>>");

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex("name", new BsonRegularExpression("Joe"));

var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

For the c# driver 2.2 (MongoDB 3.0)

```
var filter = new BsonDocument { { parameterName, new BsonDocument { { "$regex", value }, { "$options", "i"} } } }

var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

MongoDB C# driver has a [BsonRegex type](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Tutorial#CSharpDriverTutorial-BsonType) that you can use.

Regex is the closest you will get to the SQL `LIKE` statement.

Note that prefixed Regexes can use indexes: `/^Joe/` will use an index, `/Joe/` will not.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose I need to search the value of variable 'textToSearch' from a property of  Mongodb documents.

**Example:** We have to search manager in all the records where `JobModel.Title` contains `manager`. That is `textToSearch=manager` from the records. ( `textToSearch` is a string type. I have added some Regexs at the end of my answer. To cover textToSearch contains, textToSearch starts with and few more scenarios)

**Equivalent C# Code:**

```
Note: I have also shown how you can append to your existing filter, ignore it if not required.

var mongoBuilder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter = mongoBuilder.Eq(y => y.JobModel.Category, "full time");

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToSearch))
{
    textToSearch = "/.*" + textToSearch + ".*/i"; // this regex will search all the records which contains textToSearch and ignores case
    filter = filter & mongoBuilder.Regex(y => y.JobModel.Title, new BsonRegularExpression(textToSearch));
}
```

**Equivalent Mongo Query Code:**

```
db.jobs.find({ "JobModel.Category" : "full time", 
"JobModel.Title" : /.*manager.*/i })
```

**Some Useful Regex:**

- this regex will search all the records which contains textToSearch and ignores case. `textToSearch = "/.*" + textToSearch + ".*/i";`
- this regex will search all the records which starts with textToSearch and ignores case. `textToSearch = "/^" + textToSearch + "/i";`
- this regex will search all the records which starts with textToSearch and do not ignores case. `textToSearch = "/.*" + textToSearch + ".*/";`

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to @Sridhar** - similar aproach that worked for me

```
public List<SearchModel> GetSearchResult(string searchParam) => _collection.Find(new BsonDocument { { "Datetime", new BsonDocument { { "$regex", searchParam }, { "$options", "i" } } } }).ToList(); // Search DateTime "Like"
```