# MongoDB C# Text Search Returns 0 Results

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the new 2.0 C# Driver for MongoDB.  I am trying to create an autocomplete search box on my website.

I have a simple collection that has ID, Symbol, and Name:

> /* 0 */ {   "_id" : ObjectId("55743a1dbc8d1c60942ac524"),   "Symbol" :
>   "A",   "Name" : "Agilent Technologies, Inc. Comm" }
>
> /* 1 */ {   "_id" : ObjectId("55743a2dbc8d1c60942ac525"),   "Symbol" :
>   "AA",   "Name" : "Alcoa Inc. Common Stock" }
>
> /* 2 */ {   "_id" : ObjectId("55743a2dbc8d1c60942ac526"),   "Symbol" :
>   "AAC",   "Name" : "AAC Holdings, Inc. Common Stock" }
>
> /* 3 */ {   "_id" : ObjectId("55743a2dbc8d1c60942ac527"),   "Symbol" :
>   "AAL",   "Name" : "American Airlines Group, Inc." }

I created a text index using this command:

```
db.StockLookups.createIndex({Symbol: "text", Name: "text"})
```

I have the following method in my code:

```
public async Task<List<StockLookup>> SearchAsync(string searchString)
{
    var filter = Builders<StockLookup>.Filter.Text(searchString);

    return await _collection.Find(filter)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

However, it is not returning the desired results.  If I type in "AAL" I get back American Airlines which is what I want.

However, if I type in "AA" I only get back Alcoa.  In this case I would want it to return Alcoa, AAC Holdings, and American Airlines.

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct the problem?

Comment: From the mongodb documentation: "The $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match."

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after posting this question. So what kind of query do I need to be able to get the results that I am looking for?  I want a case insensitive search where either the Name or the Symbol field contains the text that is entered.

Comment: You'll need to perform a Regex search. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382307/mongodb-c-sharp-query-for-like-on-string

Comment: Thanks! That worked. If you post an answer with that response, I will accept it as the answer.