# MongoDB C# Check if a string contains a field in Expression Query

Tags: c#, mongodb

With the following model

```cs
public class Product{
    [BsonId][BsonRepresentation{BsonType.ObjectId}]
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string ItemName {get; set;}
}
```

I want to write the following query:

`var items = Db.Products.Find(x => SearchText.Contains(x.ItemName)).ToList();`

But mongodDB gives me an error saying the query is invalid and that I can't do `String.Contains(x.Field)`

So how can I check if a field is  contained within a string using `MongoDB.Driver` library

Comment: First of all, this kills the performance. The database engine now has to load all your records and do a partial match. Fulltext search exists for a reason; build an index on index time, do not scan at runtime. You can [do a regex search though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382307/mongodb-c-sharp-query-for-like-on-string).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is with regular expressions. You can try

```
var filterFirstName = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Regex("FirstName", "^" + query + ".*");
```

If you want the results to be combined, then after applying the 2 filters, you can do like

```
var finalFilter = filterFirstName & filterLastName
```

finalFIlter has the combined results.