# MongoDB use index in regular expression query

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the official C# MongoDB driver.

If I have an index on three elements {"firstname":1,"surname":1,"companyname":1} can I search the collection by using a regular expression that directly matches against the index value?

So, if someone enters "sun bat" as a search term, I would create a regex as follows
(?=.*\bsun)(?=.*\bbat).* and this should match any index entries where firstname or surname or companyname starts with 'sun' AND where firstname or surname or companyname starts with 'bat'.

If I can't do it this way, how can I do it?  The user just types their search terms, so I won't know which element (firstname, surname, companyname) each search term (sun or bat) refers to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: for MongoDB 2.4 and above you should not use this method but use [MongoDB's text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) instead.

Below is the original and still relevant answer for MongoDB < 2.4.

---

Great question. Keep this in mind:

1. MongoDB can only use one index per query.
2. Queries that use regular expressions only use an index when the regex is rooted and case sensitive.

The best way to do a search across multiple fields is to create an array of search terms (lower case) for each document and index that field. This takes advantage of the multi-keys feature of MongoDB.

So the document might look like:

```
{
    "firstname": "Tyler",
    "surname": "Brock",
    "companyname": "Awesome, Inc.",
    "search_terms": [ "tyler", "brock", "awesome inc"]
}
```

You would create an index: `db.users.ensureIndex({ "search_terms": 1 })`

Then when someone searches for "Tyler", you smash the case and search the collection using a case sensitive regex that matches the beginning of the string:

```
db.users.find({ "search_terms": /^tyler/ })
```

What mongodb does when executing this query is to try and match your term to every element of the array (the index is setup that way too -- so it's speedy). Hopefully that will get you where you need to be, good luck.

*Note: These examples are in the shell. I have never written a single line of C# but the concepts will translate even though the syntax may differ.*

Comment: See [MongoDB - Advanced Queries - Regular Expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) and [How to use MongoRegex (MongoDB C# Driver)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2699945/649852) for more info.