# How to write Mongo query with 'In' function having regex for string field?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have some data that looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ad28ac5782648b80ea2286"),
    "BookId" : 46319,
    "Title" : "test_keyword1_Test"
}
```

I am thinking to find documents with Mongo 'In' operator having regx. I used the following code for this

```
 IList<string> keywords = myKeywords.Select(x => "/" + x + "/i").ToList(); // ["/keyword1/i", "/keyword2/i"]

 Query<BookMDO>.In(m => m.Title, keywords) // db.BookMDO.find({ "Title" : { "$in" : ["/keyword1/i", "/keyword2/i"] } })
```

But the In operator having the Regx is not working. But its worked after I removed the double quotes of Regx like below

```
db.BookMDO.find({ "Title" : { "$in" : [/keyword1/i, /keyword2/i] } })
```

Is there a way to accomplish above query without quotes?

Comment: MongoRegex can be used for this. Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527443/how-to-use-mongoregex-mongodb-c-sharp-driver

Comment: Thanks Sarathy, But it will be great if the same can be achieved with 'In' operator because I have a collection of keywords. otherwise I need to loop through the keyword collection.

Comment: You should be able to put the regexps in an array and make that array the value of the `$in` key.

Comment: Thanks @wdberkeley, But here 'Title' is a string so the mongo driver 'In' operator only allows array of string as second parameter, which will create  regx having double quotes. ;-) so it wont work as shown above.

`code`public static IMongoQuery In<TMember>(Expression<Func<TDocument, TMember>> memberExpression, IEnumerable<TMember> values);`code`

In the mongo website [link]http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/[link]mentioned about In operator with regx, I am expecting to build the same with mongo DB driver.