# use of Like operator in mongodb

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

I am developing in vb.net

```
Dim dtDetails As DataTable = Utility.GetDetailsTable()
Dim resource_ids As new BsonArray

Dim dtrow = dtDetails.Select("id='" & user_id & "'")
If dtrow.Length > 0 Then
  For i As Integer = 0 To dtrow.Length - 1
   resource_ids.Add(".*" & Convert.ToString(dtrow(i)("instance_id")) & ".*")
  Next
End If

Dim queries = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("user_id", user_id),
    Query.Matches("resource_id", resource_ids )
)

Dim Docs = ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(queries)
```

Docs returns as empty. I need to send multiple resource_ids with like      operator similar to sql is resource_ids like "%abc%" or  resource_ids like  "%def%".

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using MongoRegex for this kind of query (see **[MongoDB - Advanced Queries - Regular Expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)** and **[How to use MongoRegex - MongoDB C# Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2699945/649852)** for more info). As an example in MongoDB shell, you can use `"|"` inside a regular expression to match multiple alternatives, like this:

```
db.collection.find({"resource_id": /abc|def|ghi|jkl/i})
```

The regular expression will be tested against all the entries in `resource_id` and all it takes is for one entry to match and the document will be included in the results. Do keep this in mind that MongoDB can only use one index per query and queries that use regular expressions only use an index when the regex is rooted and case sensitive. So your final code should look like:

```
Dim searchKey As String = ""

Dim dtrow = dtDetails.Select("id='" & user_id & "'")
If dtrow.Length > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtrow.Length - 1
       If i > 0 Then
          searchKey += "|"
       End If
       searchKey += Convert.ToString(dtrow(i)("instance_id"))
    Next
End If

Dim queries = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("user_id", user_id),
    Query.Matches("resource_id", new Regex(searchKey, i))
)

Dim Docs = ceilometer.GetCollection("meter").Find(queries)
```

Comment: haha, Finally u have answered. Thanks a lot again. Let me check

Comment: just change two things:  If i > 0 Then is enough instead of  If (i > 0 AndAlso i < dtrow.Length - 1) Then  and Query.Matches("resource_id", New Regex(searchKey, i)), it works. Please change so that I can mark it as answer. Thanks a lot again. If possible then help someone, sometimes, a help, can help to survive.

Comment: No worries @SyedMd.Kamruzzaman. If you remove the `AndAlso` part the regex searchKey will have an additional pipe `|` at the end of the string, won't the regex match an additional empty string?

Comment: no, it is not happening, I tested in the code. ur previous code exactly did not work. I debugged and changes above things to make them work. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Cheers!